# NextJS deployment on sub path with ingress config

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes, next.js, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am trying to deploy nextjs app in the sub path using k8s ingress.

Here is my ingress config:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: simple-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: 'nginx'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - 'example.com'
  rules:
    - host: 'example.com'
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: react-app
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /site
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: next-app
                port:
                  number: 3002
```

And here is my nextjs config:

```
const nextConfig = {
  staticPageGenerationTimeout: 60,
  assetPrefix: isProd ? '/site' : '',
  basePath: isProd ? '/site' : '',
  images: {
    path: isProd ? '/site/_next/image' : '/_next/image',
  },
}

module.exports = withNx(nextConfig)
```

With the above configuration, 1st ingress works and i am able to reach my endpoints at example.com, in the same time example.com/site returns http 404. What am i doing wrong?